# Synchronize a queue in mmap between userspace and kernelspace

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I have a piece of code whose performance I am trying to improve.  The code is conceptually simple: get some data from a sensor in kernel space every 5 ms, fill a queue with this data, and read it in userspace for processing.

Currently, I have a thread in kernel space that fills the queue, and I have a character device with a read file operation function to transfer this data to userspace with use of `copy_to_user`.

Let me show you a little skeleton of the code :

**Userspace point of view.**

```
// In userspace side

int process_queue (void)
{
    int fd = -1;
    int data_offset = 0;

    fd = open_char_device_from_kernel ();
    while (1)
    {
        // read from char device data from kernel
        err = read (fd, &ctx->data_queue[data_offset], SAMPLE_SIZE);
        data_offset = (data_offset + SAMPLE_SIZE) % QUEUE_DATA_SIZE;

        // process data
        (...)
    }

}
```

**The kernel space point of view :**

```
//In kernel side

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = xxx__ioctl,
    .read = xxx__read,
    .open = xxx__open,
    .release = xxx__release,
};

int kernel_thread(...)
{
    while (1)
    {
        // wait signal from irq
        wait_event_interruptible(wq_irq, flag_irq);
        // get data and fill queue
        (...)
        memcpy (&queue[write_offset], rx_buf[REGISTER], SAMPLE_SIZE);
        write_offset += ELEMENT_SIZE;
        if (write_offset == SIZE_QUEUE) write_offset = 0;
        up(&read_sem);
    }
}

static int xxx_read(struct file *filp, char __user *data, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    if (down_interruptible (&read_sem)) return (-EINTR);

    err = copy_to_user(data, &queue[read_offset], SAMPLE_SIZE);
    read_offset += ELEMENT_SIZE;
    if (read_offset == SIZE_QUEUE) read_offset = 0;
    return (ELEMENT_SIZE - err);
}

int probe_kernel_driver (...)
{
    (...)
    alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_no , 0, 1, DATA_DEVICE_NAME);
    cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DATA_DEVICE_NAME);
    device_create(cl, NULL, dev_no, NULL, DATA_DEVICE_NAME);
    (...)
}
```

The main idea here to remove the `copy_to_user` in this code, which is very slow. I would like to use mmap instead, and I was able to implement it on both sides to share data from kernel space to userspace. One issue remains: I don't know how to synchronize the data between userspace and kernel space. How can the userspace process know that new data is available?

Of course I don't want to use polling, or any other technique that loses the performance gain from mmap.

Comment: The performance gain you observe from using `mmap` arises *because* you have no (other) communication between kernel and user space.  It is unlikely that you can add back any kind of notification without some performance penalty, though it is reasonable to hope for substantial improvement over the original implementation.

Comment: One idea that might work:  Call `socketpair()` to create a pair of sockets, and have your userspace code `select()` on ready-for-read on one of the sockets.  After your kernel-space code has added data to the buffer, have it send a byte on the other socket.  That will cause your userspace code to wake up from `select()`, at which point it can read the byte from its socket, throw it away, then check for available data.   (My "might work" qualifier is only because I'm not sure what the rules are about writing to a socket from within kernel-space)

Answer (score 0):

Your alternatives for a userspace process to communicate with the kernel are (intentionally) limited.  They include:

- make a system call
- perform I/O on a device
- perform I/O on a kernel-mapped file, *e.g.* in `/proc`
- passively receive notification via a signal

If you're willing for the userspace process to block on data becoming available, then any of those are viable possibilities.  If you must neither poll nor block, then the last is the only option I see.

Note that making a syscall or performing I/O would not be for the purpose of retrieving the data themselves, but only for the purpose of retrieving a signal that new data are available.

You may want to look into setting up one or more suitable ioctls for your device to either directly support blocking on data becoming available or to register a process to be signaled upon the arrival of new data.

**But note well** that *all* interactions between user processes and the kernel are fairly slow, on account of substantial overhead.  The amount of data transferred during such an interaction has some relevance, but it is not the only factor.  This is why it is a good practice to minimize the number system calls your programs perform.  It follows that your `mmap`-based approach can be expected to be a win if it allows you to reduce the number of interactions with the kernel, but not so much if it only changes the mode of data transfer but still requires the same number of kernel interactions, of whatever kind.  (Accessing `mmap`ped memory is not itself an interaction with the kernel.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already try some stuff with a signal. The final performance of the new version of the code is almost the same :/ At least my code is not completely stupid right? There is not a better obvious way to do this work?

Comment: @ArthurLambert, I have not evaluated your code in any detail, as that's tangential to the question of notifying userspace about the availability of new data.  But every manner of communication between userspace and kernel space is comparatively slow.  Your approach of using `mmap` makes sense if it reduces the number of such interactions, but if it only reduces the amount of data transferred during them then it's not surprising that there is little benefit.  I will add comments to that effect to this answer.